# DynamoDB: How do you choose a primary key?

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key

Say I have a data structure like this:

- Query = Hello
- Translation = Bonjour
- Language = en-fr
- CustomerID = XYZ123
- Project = my_french_project

DynamoDB has these limits:

- Partition Key: 2KB
- Sort Key: 1KB

If my "Query" attribute needs to hold up to 300KB how do I come up with a primary key?

The "Query" is part of what makes the item unique and therefore has to be part of the Partition Key or Sort Key correct?

The only solution I can think of is some kind of hashing on the "Query" but this technically allows clashes. **Is there another way to do this?** Or is there a way to handle clashes if they were to occur?

**Update:**

I have decided to go with this structure:

- CustomerID = XYZ123 (Partition Key)
- Range = my_french_project:en-fr:8B1A9953C4611296A827ABF8C47804D7 (Sort Key with MD5 of Query)
- Project = my_french_project
- Language = en-fr
- Query = Hello
- Translation = Bonjour

I believe this allows me to make all the queries I need using [begins with](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) on the sort key when needed.

And I think it is extremely unlikely there will be a clash of the MD5 in a project with the same name and language.

Would still like to know if there are better ways.

Comment: Even if you could use the query as primary key, I probably wouldn't do it, as you'd probably get hot partitions, as they querys are probably not evenly distributed. So hashing the query and using that hash as primary key sounds like a good plan. Depending on the hash-algorithm you use the chance for collisions is negligible.

Comment: Depending on traffic you may want to check [DAX](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/dax/) to mitigate the hot partition problem

Comment: @blueCat Yeah I have looked at that, looks very promising but unfortunately not available in all regions yet and is a little too expensive compared to elasticache. Perhaps they will expand the offering at a later date, it does look a whole lot simpler then elasticache.